# Dropdown menus in python / selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Trying to autofill a form using python and selenium. Dropdown menu html is:

```
<select id="typeOfTeacher" class="chosen-select-no-single ng-untouched ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-valid ng-valid-required" required="" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : positionDetailForm.typeOfTeacher.$invalid && !positionDetailForm.typeOfTeacher.$pristine }" ng-change="vm.setRequired()" tabindex="-1" ng-model="vm.data.typeOfTeacher" name="typeOfTeacher" data-placeholder="Select" style="display: none;">
<option value="" disabled="" selected="">Select</option>
<option class="ng-binding ng-scope" value="1" ng-repeat="teacherType in vm.teacherTypes">No position at the moment</option>
<option class="ng-binding ng-scope" value="2" ng-repeat="teacherType in vm.teacherTypes">Supply</option>
<option class="ng-binding ng-scope" value="3" ng-repeat="teacherType in vm.teacherTypes">Permanent</option>
</select>
```

Python code is:

```
elem = Select(browser.find_element_by_id('typeOfTeacher'))
elem.select_by_value("1")
```

Error is "element is not currently visible and may not be interacted with".

Comment: Did you tried with `WevDriverWait` to wait until element visible before interaction??

Answer (score 0):

I have not used the python Select method, but I would guess that the error message means that the menu is not being opened, and therefore an element in the menu is still hidden and cannot be interacted with.

Try something like this:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_id('typeOfTeacher').click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[value=\"1\"]").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work

```
element = driver.find_element_by_id('typeOfTeacher').click()
element.find_element_by_xpath(".//option[@value='1']").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like timing issue. You should try using [Waits](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#waits).

I would suggest you, use `WebDriverWait` to wait until dropdown visible before interaction as below :-

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "typeOfTeacher")))

select = Select(element)
select.select_by_value("1")
```